# How should I subscribe to the Facebook 'Subscribe' button?

Tags: javascript, facebook, events

How can I subscribe to run a callback when someone presses the NEW Facebook Subscribe button? I assumed it would be just like the Like button and I would run:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
   alert('whatevs');
});
```

but that doesn't seem to trigger at all.

Is there a particular order that I have to run this in? My entire block of code is as follows:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init();
    FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
        alert('whatevs');
    });
    FB.XFBML.parse();
});
```